# Windows 10 - How can I fix - C:\ Ace entries not in canonical order

Tags: windows, cygwin, icacls

I have run into an issue with my windows backup software that I believe is due to an issue with permissions on my C:\ drive. I am using cygwin which can cause issues.

The problem manifests itself by the Veritas SRS software not being able to snapshot the C:\ drive due to issues with VSS.

When attempting to run a utility that diagnoses and fixes issues with VSS (vss-doctor by Acronis), it indicates that the SYSTEM account does not have Full Control access to C:\

When I try to run the fix, the utility complains that that the access control list is not in canonical order. I can confirm this by running:

```
C:\>icacls C:\ /verify
C:\: Ace entries not in canonical order.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

When I try to reset, I receive this error (I am running the command prompt in Administrator mode):

```
C:\>icacls C:\ /reset
C:\: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

What can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: First of all, do not try to change the order of the ACL entries. They are done that way on purpose to properly emulate POSIX permissions. Non-canonical order is perfectly legal and valid. Second, open an issue with Veritas SRS. They may have a workaround you can use. This must be a problem for all users of Veritas SRS and cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am in the process of trying to get veritas to help. I was able to at least change the ACL to grant full control to SYSTEM, but that did not correct the issue. I had to reboot the computer in to recovery mode and use the command console to use the icacls tool.

I don't think cygwin should have changed any of the permissions on the C:\ folder.

Comment: I suggest you visit the cygwin site and subscribe to the cygwin users email list. A question asked there will be seen by the developers and maintainers who can give you the best advice.